# Why is Talend skipping more rows than just those that have a unique Key?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, talend

I have been loading data into MySQL from a CSV file via Talend, the SQL table has a unique key on a number (that isn't the primary key) to ensure no duplication.

Example Table:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `network_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `num2_unique` (`num2`)
```

I've found that a bit of data hasn't been loaded and the only reason I can find is to do with the unique key on num1.
Out of about 550k lines of data 1.5k lines were missing from the table once run.
I isolated the 1.5k lines and loaded them separately which worked fine, but I have no idea why they didn't load in the first instance.

To check I tried this again with just 50 rows, one of which was already in the SQL table so should be skipped by Talend when loading, however Talend picked up the duplicated unique key but loaded none of the lines loaded to the SQL table. Once the single duplicate line was removed from the CSV file the other 59 loaded perfectly.

Any advice on why this is happening and / or a way around it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your tDBOutput component, check whether you are using "batch insert" (or "extend insert" or something similar, the name depends on the db component). Bulk insert is often the default behaviour : it will roll back all the data you are trying to insert if a problem is encountered in the batch.
Also did you check your schema on the dboutput component ? There is a "key" column in it (checkbox) make sure that "num1" is not set as key.

Comment: The "extend insert" was selected with 100 rows per insert. I've unticked this and it seems to be working now.
Thank you very much.